# target responseXML data for CSS

Tags: javascript

I have a basic XMLHttpRequest that returns data from an xml file to a ul that I place into a div on my webpage:

```
var request;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
request.open("GET", "data.xml");
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if((request.readyState ===4) && (request.status ===200)){
        var items = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('title');
        output = "<ul>";
        for (i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        output += "<li>" + items[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</li>";
        }
    output += "</ul>"
    document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = output;
    }
}
request.send();
```

So far so good. Displays on the page as expected. However, if I view source, the new list doesn't appear in the html structure. And if I try to style my new list with something like:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var cssObj = {
        "background-color": "#333",
        "color": "#FFF",
    }
    $("ul:last li").css(cssObj);
});
```

nothing happens. having imported the data into my html, how do I then target it with css and style it?

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest.open` is not called to read data from local files.  It expects an URL.

Comment: When I serve the file from my web server I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not see in view source because you load content by ajax. you should change styles after request not on document ready. or you can use class instead of styles, then you do not care when styles will change automatically after you load html in to your page.

and new content your can see (chrome or ff) by inspecting element

```
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if ((request.readyState === 4) && (request.status === 200)) {
        console.log(request);
        var items = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('title');
        output = "<ul>";
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            output += "<li>" + items[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</li>";
        }
        output += "</ul>"
        document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = output;
        var cssObj = {
            "background-color": "#333",
                "color": "#FFF",
        }
        $("ul:last li").css(cssObj);
    }
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tTwFk/1/)